# Had to cancel first interview due to flu, company not responding to my email about re-scheduling. Should I re-apply?

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, job-search, follow-up

I had an interview setup about a week ago, but had to cancel due to having the flu. After a brief email correspondence with the person who I'm suppose to interview with, he tells me it's fine, and that they will get back with a new interview date the following day.

3 days pass. No response. I write him an email asking if we should find a new date for the interview. No response.

Is this a red flag? Should I re-apply? Is this a weird rejection?
The job is still posted, so I assume they haven't found another candidate.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a proper ghosting until they've ignored at least one phone call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Companies get hundreds of emails daily to their recruitment team. Emailing is likely going to get lost amongst these until found at a later date.

> Is this a red flag? Should I re-apply? Is this a weird rejection?

No, No and No.

Just call them to get an answer. If they ignore the phone call, call again.

Comment: It could be a red flag, if they really have such an issue with someone calling out because of the flu that they wouldn't work with them to reschedule. But at 3 days, I'm inclined to agree that this is just a case of something slipping through the cracks.

Comment: Agreed - for all we know, the person who they were email corresponding with is also home with flu and nobody arranged to pick up their email. The surest way to find out is to give them a call.

Answer (score 1):

I usually recommend waiting at least a week before sending a follow E-Mail. Your contact person might be sick or on vacation, or just busy.

Don't reapply or anything like that.

Just wait for a week. If you don't get any more response, just assume they are not interested anymore. But if you are really interested in this particular job, try giving them a phone call after one week as a final resort.

Answer (score 1):

As I read it:

> I had a flu, I applied to reschedule and after 3 days, they still did not get back.

Well, nothing to panic, *yet*.

Usually, it is estimated that, for a simple flu it takes 5-7 days for the symptoms to go away and 7-10 days to recover completely. maybe the company just wants to reschedule on a later date, giving enough room for you to recover complete (if the interview is remote) and to avoid possibility of getting other employees infected (in case in-person interview). They just may not have a fixed schedule for the interview that far ahead (2-4 weeks) and taking their time to fix a later date on which it would be possible for them to get that interview arranged.

Get in touch with them, (over phone, if you know the contact numbers, if you don't, search/ask for it) and gently remind them about the requested reschedule. As mentioned in other answers, emails tend to get lost, never fully rely on them.

However, now it is too early and not correct to think about

> *Is this a red flag? Should I re-apply? Is this a weird rejection?*

You don't have any grounds to start thinking about these.